# Windows bounce to the first monitor after hibernate (in windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have a windows ultimate 32 bit with 2 monitors,
multiple displays set to: "Extend these displays"
After hibernate, all the windows are back in the first monitor, and I need to re-drag them (or Win-shift-arrow them) all over again.

Any ideas?

it seems like a duplicate of:
[Windows 7 dual monitor windows move when screen is locked](https://superuser.com/questions/409468/windows-7-dual-monitor-windows-move-when-screen-is-locked)
but I didn't see a clear answer in there...

Comment: What is your video card you are using?  Have you updated to the most recent driver revision?

Comment: tried it - it didn't solve it - now the main screen goes to hibernate and doesn't wakeup and the second screen keeps on
When I manually restart the main screen, all the windows jump to it
The graphics card is Intel G45/G43