# How do I stop all my open windows from moving to one monitor every time I lock my screen?

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-10, macbook-pro-retina

It's getting pretty annoying, I lock my screen then when I come back and unlock all my windows have been moved to a single monitor instead of staying where they were. I don't recall Windows ever behaving this way before 10. Any idea how to get them to stay where they are? For what it's worth, it's a 13" Retina MBP.

EDIT:

One is connected via HDMI, the other is connected via the mini-displayport(thunderbolt)-to HDMI adapter. When I lock the screen (not closing laptop at all) **all the windows end up on the screen that is connected via the HDMI port/cable,** which is also the one set as the 'main display' in Windows.

Comment: Are you certain your MacBook is maintaining a stable connection to each of your monitors while locked? If you're also using your internal monitor, closing your MacBook's lid would technically "disconnect" that monitor, triggering the behavior you're seeing - this behavior, in my experience, predates Windows 10 for several versions.

Comment: @Psycogeek good point, added those details

Comment: This is common, many HDMI displays "disconnect" when they shut off, causing Windows to relocated the windows for you (since it thinks the monitor was unplugged). It's not unique to Windows 10, or even windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 7 dual monitor windows move when screen is locked](http://superuser.com/questions/409468/windows-7-dual-monitor-windows-move-when-screen-is-locked)