# Windows 10 switching user causes dialogs to lose their position

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, fast-user-switching

I have two large monitors (identical 4k resolution) configured as side-by-side extended. These work fine in general use, but when I switch users, the dialogs/windows that are open lose their position.

I quite often dock windows to the left/right of each screen, giving me 4 portrait windows to work with, or even one in each corner, giving me 8 smaller working areas.

When I switch users, then back again, nothing is in the right place, and sometimes it swaps the windows from one screen to the other.

In some circumstances, if I have Visual Studio open, it crashes when I switch back to the original user.

Is this a known issue? Anybody know if there's a work-around?

Comment: Worth a read... https://superuser.com/questions/409468/windows-7-dual-monitor-windows-move-when-screen-is-locked

Comment: I think it is to do with the monitors momentarily switching off/on, but I'm not "sleeping", just switching users.

Comment: Yes, but although your monitors aren't "sleeping," when you utilize the Switch User function, from your original user account's perspective they actually *are*.  As a result, you are seeing the same symptoms as you would in the previous question that Digital Lightcraft referenced.